# Why was NWS shifted from green hydraulic to yellow hydraulic system in the A320?

Tags: airbus-a320, hydraulic-system, nosewheel

In older Airbus A320s, the NWS (nose wheel steering) was on the green hydraulic system and now it's on yellow. What's the reason for the change?

Answer (score 4):

This enhanced package (green to yellow change) since serial number [1939](https://www.planespotters.net/airframe/airbus-a318-100-n801fr-frontier-airlines/elm6vr)<sup>[1]</sup> had the following objectives in mind:<sup>[2]</sup>

> Objectives:
>
> - Avoid simultaneous loss of Normal braking and nose wheel steering functions on a single hydraulic failure. [normal braking is green]
> - Avoid loss of nose wheel steering function due to ADIRU or LGCIU failure. [ADR 1+3 failure results in NWS failure; ADIRU 1 and 3 control the Green shut off valve once the L/G is retracted and speed is above ~260 knots]
> - Make the nose wheel steering function available after a landing gear free fall extension. [L/G extension is green]

(My explanation is in square brackets.)

As a bonus, it would have permitted the eTaxi option (announced in [2013](https://www.greencarcongress.com/2013/12/20131218-airbus.html); scrapped in [2019](https://www.reuters.com/article/us-safran-airbus-taxi-idUSKBN1Y72MN)). This way, the APU would have supplied power to the powered-wheels, as well as hydraulics for steering and braking (alternate), all without a tug, and without having to power the Green system via the PTU.<sup>[1]</sup>

---

1: Airbus [FAST magazine](https://www.airbus.com/aircraft/support-services/publications/fast-magazine.html) #51
2: A320-family flight deck and systems briefing for pilots

Comment: Didn't know that eTaxi was scrapped. Bummer.